# Matlab double vs uint8 for a [0-255] gray scale image

Tags: matlab, double

I have a gray scale image in Matlab.

I noticed that some image processing algorithms in Matlab are affected if I keep the image in a 'double' or 'uint8' array. I realized that I was using 'double' even if 'uint8' was sufficient. It seems that it does matter when calling Matlab motion detection algorithms.

Is this due to representation of the 'double' numbers? I know that "floating-point calculations have rounding error" due to having to represent a number in exactly 32/64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

`uint8` computations have a much larger rounding error than `double`.

What you are seeing is because MATLAB expects double images to be in the range [0,1]. If your images have a larger range, they might end up clipped in some algorithms.

Other than that, expect doubles to yield better (more precise) answers. `uint8` calculations *could* be faster, though this is not always the case.

Comment: Yes. One needs to use im2double. My problem was that my image became double with values [0 - 255] because of automatic conversion in Matlab. And it did not work properly later.